# Copy contents of one DeviceContext to another DeviceContext

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I've never done any GDI programming and despite taking several shots in the dark and searching the documentation I haven't found the correct way to do copy the contents of one DC to another DC.

The code I have at the moment is below. I don't understand why it's not working (the window remains just remains blank after creation).

```
SIZE srcSize;
// ... Get size of source DC

HDC destDC = ...;   // from GetDC(myWindow), myWindow was
                    // sized before this to properly contain source
HDC sourceDC = ...;

HBITMAP buffer = CreateCompatibleBitmap(sourceDC, srcSize.cx, srcSize.cy);
HGDIOBJ oldObj = SelectObject(destDC, buffer);
BitBlt(destDC, 0, 0, srcSize.cx, srcSize.cy, sourceDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(destDC, oldObj);
DeleteObject(buffer);

//... ReleaseDC()s here
```

What's the proper way this is done?

Comment: One thing maybe i should add is that I'm not calling this from the `WM_PAINT` message, and don't handle that in the WindowProcedure, should I override that? It might be that the `DefWindowProc` handler for `WM_PAINT` just paints the window white after I copy.

Comment: Yes, this should be in `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: @cplusplus, yes of course you need to paint the window in WM_PAINT or the defwindowproc will paint it for you... You also need to revalidate the window, to prevent it being called multiple times.

Comment: Also you need to actually have something on the bitmap you copy from.... If you copy an empty bitmap you are not going to see anything. Also I assume SourceDC is a memory DC???

Comment: You destroy immedately result of your blit (`buffer`), switch `destDC` and `sourceDC` in your `BitBlt` to see that window rect updated by some blackness or whatever the intial content of your newly created bitmap is.

Comment: @Ben `sourceDC` is from `IDirectDrawSurface::GetDC()`.

I can't access `sourceDC` in the scope of the `WM_PAINT` message in the window procedure... what if all I do in `WM_PAINT` is `ValidateRect()`?

Comment: Why are you trying to select a bitmap into the destination DC? Can't you just Blt directly onto the DC? Also consider creating a memory DC and associated bitmap, and keeping it permanently. When the DD surface changes you can copy it to the memory DC/bitmap and in WM_PAINT you can copy it from the memory DC to the window DC.

Comment: I was under the impression you always needed to have a bitmap selected in the destination DC, but i tried to blt directly on to it like you suggested and that worked. Adding solution code and marking that as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing necessary to copy from one DC to another is a `BitBlt`. Code that works is below.

```
SIZE srcSize;
// ... Get size of source DC

HDC destDC = ...;   // from GetDC(myWindow), myWindow was
                    // sized before this to properly contain source
HDC sourceDC = ...;

BitBlt(destDC, 0, 0, srcSize.cx, srcSize.cy, sourceDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
//... ReleaseDC()s here
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear to me what you are trying to do. First off, why create the new bitmap and select it into the window (sorry, "client area") DC? All you want is paint/draw the window, isn't it? This is not needed then. The destDC is exactly the window's client area surface.

Does sourceDC really contain anything? For example, does it have a bitmap slected into it?

And of course, you SHOULD process WM_PAINT. If you process this message the window is validated, and you are not required to validate it explicitly. Using GetDC()/ReleaseDC() is called "drawing", as opposed to "painting". In an application I made in the past I had to use both methods, painting (processing WM_PAINT) for responding to resizing, exiting from minimized state and bringing the window to foreground (if previously obscured by another) and drawing, for making certain changes immediately visible (instead of invalidating the window and waiting for the application to nearly enter the idle state first - pls note that WM_PAINT is a low-priority message).

Hope this helps