# Picture from one dc to another

Tags: mfc, raster, gdi

I have two classes with windows in one program (the view, and dialog), that must show pictures.

The view take picture from disk like:

```
    CClientDC dc(this); 
GetClientRect(&rc);     
dcMem.DeleteDC();
hBmp = NULL;;
m_bmpBack.DeleteObject();
hBmp = LoadImage(NULL,"d:/USBconn.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);   
GetObject ( hBmp, sizeof(bm), &bm );    
m_bmpBack.Attach(hBmp);     
dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
hbmpOld = (HBITMAP)dcMem.SelectObject(m_bmpBack);   
dc.StretchBlt(rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom,&dcMem, 0, 0, (int)bm.bmWidth, (int)bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
```

How to "BitBlt" image from this dc in to the dc in the other class and window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy contents of one DeviceContext to another DeviceContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407500/copy-contents-of-one-devicecontext-to-another-devicecontext)